# dynamically indent strings in Java

Tags: java, string

Good afternoon friends!

I am having a question for dynamically indenting strings.

I have a chart of accounts, for example:

- 3.01.01 - ACCOUNT NAME
- 3.01.01.01 - ACCOUNT NAME
- 3.01.01.01.0010 - ACCOUNT NAME
- 3.01.01.03 - ACCOUNT NAME
- 3.01.01.03.0003 - ACCOUNT NAME

And I'd like to indent according to your "level" (breaking the string in the dot)

Example: 3.01.01 = 3 levels
3.01.01.01 = 4 levels

I would like you to insert X tab (x = level), any suggestions on how to do this?

Expected result:

- ...3.01.01 - account name
- ....3.01.01.01 - account name
- .....3.01.01.01.0010 - account name
- ....3.01.01.03 - account name
- .....3.01.01.03.0003 - account name

Comment: To those voting to close because “Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, ” … this question in not seeking debugging help. This Question is asking for help in devising an algorithm for manipulating text. Stack Overflow was invented for just this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Can easily be done using regex, like this:

```
String indent = num.replaceAll("[^.]+\\.?", "\t");
```

*Demo* (using `.` instead of tab to show indentation):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    print("3.01.01", "ACCOUNT NAME");
    print("3.01.01.01", "ACCOUNT NAME");
    print("3.01.01.01.0010", "ACCOUNT NAME");
    print("3.01.01.03", "ACCOUNT NAME");
    print("3.01.01.03.0003", "ACCOUNT NAME");
}
public static void print(String num, String name) {
    String indent = num.replaceAll("[^.]+\\.?", ".");
    System.out.println(indent + num + " - " + name);
}
```

*Output*

```
...3.01.01 - ACCOUNT NAME
....3.01.01.01 - ACCOUNT NAME
.....3.01.01.01.0010 - ACCOUNT NAME
....3.01.01.03 - ACCOUNT NAME
.....3.01.01.03.0003 - ACCOUNT NAME
```